# When does the nearest neighbor heuristic fail for the Traveling Salesperson?

Tags: algorithms, heuristics, traveling-salesman

Can you provide an example of NN algorithm failure on the Euclidean traveling salesman problem?

I was trying to construct a specific example of this for my friends and was failing.

Comment: Please give (an outline of) the algorithm you are referring to. Also, please include your attempts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a ladder

```
a----b----c
|    |    |
d----e----f
```

Say length of `a-b` is $2$ and length of `a-d` is $1$. The optimal route is `a-b-c-f-e-d-a`, $10$ units long. Starting at `a`, NN would produce `a-d-e-b-c-f-a` which is $7 + \sqrt{17} > 11$ units long.

There is actually a four node example, a rhombus

```
  A
 /|\
B-+-C
 \|/
  D
```

Say length of `B-C` is $10$, length of `A-D` is $24$ and thus length of `A-B` is $13$. The optimal route is `A-B-D-C-A`, $52$ units long. NN would produce the path `A-B-C-D-A`, $60$ units long.

Comment: Very interesting, do you think it's possible to generalize this down to less than 6 nodes?

Comment: Apparently it is. I'm not sure whether this can be called generalizing though...

Answer (score 5):

The following answer is to give an intuition of how a situation can look that fails.  Karolis Juodelė's answer is much better than this, but I find the following example to give a nice intuition.

Let's say that we look for shortest TSP path, and not cycle, with predefined starting vertex, consider the graph below with X being the starting vertex, one dash means distance one, and two edges means distance two:

O--X-O-O-O-O

Going left immediately, and then all the way to the right gives a cost of 8, whereas going NN, i.e., right first, gives cost 9.

Comment: The answer is a too weak. It's as if the flaw of NN was a random starting point.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Yes, I know.  I upvoted your answer, explained in the post that your answer is better, and also pointed out that this is for intuition purposes only.